# Print Webpage as it appears using HTML

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I would like to create a button using only HTML, to print the web page just as the way it appears on the browser.

But this basic code prints even the hidden blocks.

```
<a class="print-page" href="javascript:window.print()"><i class="fas fa-print"></i> Print This Page</a>
```

Could someone help me please!

Here The button generates this pdf with above code.

[image]

but the problem, it takes the whole body of the page, which has blocks hidden for computers but visible for mobile phones.
It is printing all the body including hidden blocks.
like in this below screen shot, this are normally hidden blocks for computer browsers.
[image]

Comment: Could you put a runnable snippet into your question - it doesn't have to be complex, just enough content to show us how things are being hidden. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth i attached some screenshots, basically i don't want that it prints the hidden blocks from the web page

Comment: I have tried the code you have given with some content in the page, some with visibility: hidden and some with display: none. None of it is printed out, the only thing that happens is that space is left where the visibility: hidden elements were, this is correct behavior. So as it stands the error you report is not apparently reproducible. Please put up code which reproduces your problem otherwise your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Ah! I now see that you aren't just printing it, but saving it as pdf and there is more information about mobile devices. Please put up the actual code.

Comment: _"blocks hidden for computers but visible for mobile phones. It is printing all the body including hidden blocks"_ - then printing to PDF, is apparently triggering your mobile styles, and not the desktop ones. Add something to your stylesheet, that explicitly hides these elements in print mode, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: What have you got your media break points set at? And what size paper are you telling the pdf to 'use'?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by including some `@media print` rules in a stylesheet.

```
.print-only{
 display: none;
}
.screen-only{
 display:block;
}
@media print {
 .print-only{
  display: block;
 }
 .screen-only{
  display:none;
 }

 .something1,
 .something2 {
  display:none;
 }
}
```